# Ansible task to confirm if a process is running

Tags: ansible

Ansible 2.1

In the playbook, I started a process:

```
- name: Start Automation Agent, and enable start on boot
  service: name=mongodb-mms-automation-agent state=started enabled=yes
```

From play recap, it appears the process has successfully started.

```
TASK [install : Start automation agent, and enable start on boot] **************
changed: [server1]
```

However, when log in to remote host and do a `ps`, the process is not running. Checking on process log it had failed some pre-requisite (intended).

How do I write a task in a playbook to confirm the process has successfully started?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can check with the `failed` Jinja2 filter after running your command that checks if the process is running.

Here is an example that uses the output of the command `systemctl status apache2` to decide if Apache is running:

```
- name: Check if Apache is running
  command: systemctl status apache2
  ignore_errors: yes
  changed_when: false
  register: service_apache_status

- name: Report status of Apache
  fail:
    msg: |
      Service apache2 is not running.
      Output of `systemctl status apache2`:
      {{ service_apache_status.stdout }}
      {{ service_apache_status.stderr }}
  when: service_apache_status | failed
```

If the command of the first task failed, the second task will fail and show why the first task failed.

The return code is stored in `service_apache_status.rc`.

Example output of a failure:

```
TASK: [Check if Apache is running] *********************** 
failed: [localhost] => {"changed": false, "cmd": ["systemctl", "status", "apache2"], "delta": "0:00:00.009379", "end": "2016-06-06 15:17:27.827172", "rc": 3, "start": "2016-06-06 15:17:27.817793", "stdout_lines": ["* apache2.service", "   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)", "   Active: inactive (dead)"], "warnings": []}
stdout: * apache2.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)
...ignoring

TASK: [Report status of Apache] ***************************
failed: [localhost] => {"failed": true}
msg: apache2 is not running
systemctl status apache2 output:
* apache2.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

Here is different (albeit possibly less reliable) way, using `pgrep`, to check if the process is running:

```
- name: Check if Apache is running
  shell: pgrep apache2
  ignore_errors: yes
  changed_when: false
  register: service_apache_status

- name: Report status of Apache
  fail:
    msg: |
      Service apache2 is not running.
      Return code from `pgrep`:
      {{ service_apache_status.rc }}
  when: service_apache_status.rc != 0
```

Comment: How does `when: service_apache_status | failed` works? Does it look for a `failed` token in `service_apache_status`?

Comment: @HowardLee: I believe it checks the return code, and if it is not `0`, it's considered `failed`.

Comment: instead of ps | grep you could try `pgrep apache2`

Comment: @madeddie: I like it.  Answer updated to suggest `pgrep`!

Comment: If you're checking services, you can do it the Ansible way by running the service_facts module and then checking ansible_local.services["apache2"].status as well.

Answer (score 5):

This is what I do now:

```
- name: Confirm Automation Agent is running
  command: service mongodb-mms-automation-agent status
  register: agent_status
  failed_when: "'NOT' in agent_status.stdout"
  changed_when: False
```

`failed_when` is introduced in 1.4. `changed_when: False` is used to suppress change status. [Read more](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_error_handling.html).